# Node.js - How to get callback function's variable out of function?

Tags: node.js, callback

**balance.js**

```
var CoinStack = require('coinstack-sdk-js')
var accessKey = 'c7dbfacbdf1510889b38c01b8440b1';
var secretKey = '10e88e9904f29c98356fd2d12b26de';
var client = new CoinStack(accessKey, secretKey);

client.getBalance(address, function(err, balance) {
    console.log('balance', balance)
});
```

I have a this code, then i want to get var balance out of function

i don't know what to do, i want fixed code

i need your helps

Comment: The ONLY place you can use `balance` is in your callback or in a function you call from the callback.  That's how async code works in Javascript.  Get used to it, design your code to work that way, stop looking for a way around it.  Any code that needs `balance` should be in your callback or in a function that you call from the callback and you pass the `balance` to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, consider using Promises like this :

```
var CoinStack = require('coinstack-sdk-js')
var accessKey = 'c7dbfacbdf1510889b38c01b8440b1';
var secretKey = '10e88e9904f29c98356fd2d12b26de';
var client = new CoinStack(accessKey, secretKey);
let balancePromise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

   client.getBalance(address, function(err, balance) {
     if(err) 
        reject(err)
     else 
       resolve(balance);
   });
})

// how to get balance value
balancePromise.then((balance)=>{
  console.log('balance', balance)
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log('error', error)
})
```

Comment: Promises are great, but they aren't really relevant to the OP's question.  You still end up with `balance` in a callback.

Comment: Yep, and that's the answer to the question.  There's no way to do it.  That's what the OP needs to understand.  That's the real answer to their question.